# gdb print static variable from function

Tags: c++, gdb

We have a C++ program such as:

```
int&
Instance()
{
    static int test;
    return test;
}

int
main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    int& test = Instance();
    printf("%d\n",test);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now I'm trying to print `Instance::test`, as suggested by some gdb documentation: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_52.html

However, this yields:

```
(gdb) p Instance::test

No symbol "test" in specified context.
```

I'm compiling with `-O0 -g`.

Comment: I'm wondering whether it's undefined behavior to pass references to a function `printf` that knows nothing about what a reference is. It just seems wrong to me.  I'll stick my neck out -- I don't have the C++ spec in front of me right now, but I'm hedging my bet that the code has undefined behavior due to passing a reference to `printf()`

Comment: Why wouldn't it be fine? I'm using a reference which will result in a copy of an integer. The only issue that I could see is with the vararg implementation. In my experience and this example, it works fine. But this is also not the question at hand

Comment: `The only issue that I could see is with the vararg implementation`  Which was my point.  Plus, comments are meant for comments, that's I didn't post my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
(gdb) p 'Instance()::test'
```

works for me on Ubuntu 14.04, gdb 7.7, g++ 4.8.2 .  How did I know that was the symbol?

```
$ nm -C a.out | grep test
0000000000601040 d Instance()::test
```

Comment: Correct. The key is the single quotes.

Comment: @Sioux Yes - I should have called attention to that from the beginning.

Comment: I was having a similar problem, and your `nm` trick solved it for me. However, the symbol was `prevRev.6906`. It worked, but what is this symbol, and how was I supposed to guess it?

Comment: @baruch what compiler, version, and flags are you using? And are you compiling the code in the original question, or other code?

Comment: Other code. gcc (mingw64) 4.9.2, `-g`. In my code, the static variable scope is not directly in a function, but rather in an inner block (it is declared within an `if` block)